# Excel: get data from sheet2 to sheet1

Tags: excel

I have two `sheets`, both `sheets` has common value id. What I want to achieve is to get certain column data from `sheet2`, when id matches.

**Example**:

```
sheet1:
Column A = id
Column B = name
Column C = here I want values from sheet2 from column B
sheet2:
Column A = id
Column B = Birth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this previous answer to a similar questions [Excel Find column value in another column and return value next to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834282/excel-find-column-value-in-another-column-and-return-value-next-to-it/39834687#39834687)

You should use the newer Index-match functions.

If sheet 1 is

```
id  name   Sheet2ColumnB
1   James
2   Will
4   Mike
5   Ed
```

Sheet 2

```
id  Birth
1   1/1/1999
2   5/17/2012
3   8/9/2011
4   3/31/1764
5   5/23/1777
```

Then you could use a function

```
= INDEX(Sheet2!B$2:B$6,MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A$2:A$6,0))
```

I made an assumption that your Birth column was actually a date.  If you are doing dates or some other format, make sure you format the cells in Column C of sheet 1 (labelled in this example Sheet2ColumnB) do be what you want for display purposes, otherwise this function will just show you the underlying value on sheet 1.   Good Luck.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, but unfortunately I cant get this function to work in excel 2016.

Comment: I actually mocked this up in Excel 2016.  I'm happy to share that file if provided email or upload location.

Comment: I got it to work, needed to use semicolon, comma does not work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use VLOOKUP function for this purpose. 
Example:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, sheet2!A2:B40,2) //[Copy and Paste this in C2 of sheet1]
=VLOOKUP(A3, sheet2!A2:B40,2) //[Copy and Paste this in C3 of sheet1]
.
.
.
=VLOOKUP(A40, sheet2!A2:B40,2) //[Copy and Paste this in C40 of sheet1]
```

in vlookup function use your exact sheetName instead of sheet2.

NB: if the birth column type is Date in sheet2, make the column type Date for Column C in sheet1.